# Multiple Types of in app purchase

Tags: iphone

I want to know is it possible to have multiple types of in app purchase in my app.

For example: can I have non consumable & subscription based product in my app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,you can maintain all the in-app-purchases in your app only the condition is that product must be registered in the iTunes connect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  My app has auto-renewing subscriptions as well as consumable offerings.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can set multiple purchase type in iTunes connect.